# Creating a new editable row in a b-table without jquery in bootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lumen, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to create something like this [demo](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/snippets/preview.php?topic=bootstrap&file=table-with-add-and-delete-row-feature) in vueJs, I'm using b-table from bootstrap-vue.

this is the b-table I've made

```
                    <b-row>
                        <b-col>
                            <b-table
                                show-empty
                                stacked="md"
                                :items="fetched_classf"
                                :fields="classes"
                                :current-page="currentPage"
                                :per-page="perPage"
                                :filter="filter"
                                :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
                                :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
                                :sort-direction="sortDirection"
                                @filtered="onFilteredDept"
                                id="tabel"
                                >
                                <template slot="id" slot-scope="row" style="text-align: left">
                                    {{ row.value }}
                                </template>

                                <template class="add_desc" slot="class_desc" slot-scope="row">
                                    {{ row.value }}
                                </template>

                                <template slot="action" slot-scope="row">
                                        <b-button size="sm" class="mr-1" style="padding: 0rem 2px;">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg "></i>
                                        </b-button>
                                </template>

                                <template slot="row-details" slot-scope="row">
                                    <b-card>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li v-for="(value, key) in row.item" :key="key">{{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    </b-card>
                                </template>

                                <template slot="selectedDept" slot-scope="{ rowSelected }">
                                    <span v-if="rowSelected">✔</span>
                                </template>
                            </b-table>
                        </b-col>
                    </b-row>
```

and this is the method to add the new row:

```
        addRow(){
            this.clicked = true;
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            var parent = document.getElementById("tabel");
            parent.appendChild(input);


            this.idbaru = this.terbesar;
            var id_incremented =  this.idbaru+1
            console.log ('id_incremented ',id_incremented)
            this.fetched_classf.push({id: id_incremented, dept_id: id_incremented, class_desc: input})
            this.terbesar = id_incremented
        },
```

I end up getting something like this: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrpoB.jpg)
I don't have any ideas since I'm new to this template

Comment: I dont know vuejs but u can add a new key isEditable==false with each of your row and chnage value of iseditable to true while click on edit button. at that time hide current row and show editable div in place of that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to only add one row?

If it's the case, you can use this solution below:

```
<tr v-if="displayNewRow">
  <td> <input/> </td>
  <td> <input/> </td>
  <td> <input/> </td>
</tr>
```

And you set the variable displayNewRow to false at the beginning, but when you want to display it you can set this variable to true.